# Pattern matching Powershell - Multiline

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching

```
$EvtMessage= @"
A member was removed from a security-enabled global group.

Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-1232435678-3215674231-8564287451-324516
    Account Name:       tstact.ntt.admin
    Account Domain:     DT
    Logon ID:       0x1E3363AEE

Member:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-1523435678-3215674231-8564287451-324516
    Account Name:       CN=DT DEST02,OU=NoStandard,OU=Users,OU=My Org B2B TEST,DC=DT,DC=ad,DC=local

Group:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-1523435678-3215674231-8564287451-324516
    Group Name:     TSK-DT-S-D-SRVAdmin
    Group Domain:       DT

Additional Information:
    Privileges: 
"@
```

I need to extract whatever string that is present in the position of "**tstact.ntt.admin**" above (under the **Subject:**, not **Member:**) using **-Match** or **Select-String**. Could you please help me with the PowerShell regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tags matter: without the [tag:powershell] tag, the relevant experts won't see your question.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the perfect solution, but I ended up with the below:

**@($EvtMessage -split [environment]::NewLine)[4] -match '.*Account Name:(?.*)$'**

**$matches.AccountName**

This solution assumes the format of the message structure (in terms of the individual lines) does not change. Fingers crossed...

Comment: I think due to Stack overflow meta formatting characters * are eliminated in the above powershell line. It should be @($EvtMessage -split [environment]::NewLine)[4] -match '.*Account Name:(?.*)$'

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).